# Need a Syncroot for a LinkedList(of T)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, collections, synchronization

I am using VB.Net and would like to use a LinkedList. Only problem is that it is a multithreaded application. I saw from MSDN that Syncroot is an explicit implementation of the ICollection Interface. I found people wanting to do similar things with List(Of T). It seems that the solution there is to cast the list to the interface.

I have tried to do what I would imagine to be a similar thing in VB.Net, basically:

```
Dim TestLinkedList = New LinkedList(Of Long)
SyncLock (Ctype(TestLinkedList, ICollection)).SyncRoot
    .
    .
    .
End SyncLock
```

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, that's about all that can be said for it.  SyncRoot was a mistake from .NET 1.1, there's no reason to continue the practice.

```
Dim list = New LinkedList(Of Long)
Dim listLock = New Object
...

SyncLock(listLock)
...
End SyncLock
```

Answer (score 0):

`ICollection.SyncRoot` is generally considered a bad idea. You should either lock the collection itself, or lock on a separate lock object you create