# List<T> doesn't implements SyncRoot!

Tags: c#, collections, synchronization

Everyone use lot of List. I need to iterate over this list, so I use the known [SyncRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot.aspx) pattern.

Recently I noticed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227833/need-a-syncroot-for-a-linkedlistof-t) post that the SyncRoot should be avoided in favor of "embedded" thread-safety (each method will lock on an private object without exposing it using SyncRoot property). I can understand it, and partially I agree on that.

The question is that [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class doesn't implements the SyncRoot property, even if implements the [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.collections.icollection.aspxBlockquote) interface, which expose the *SyncRoot* property. I say this bause the code

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>()
 list.SyncRoot;
```

give me the following compiler error:

> error CS0117: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'SyncRoot'

...If this is true, how could I synchronize a public property of type List<T> when iterating over it?

Comment: I have never found SyncRoot to work well in real life, as locking tends to work better at a higher level, rather then just locking single collections

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is actually implemented explicitly.

```
object ICollection.SyncRoot
{
    get
    {
        if (this._syncRoot == null)
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this._syncRoot, new object(), null);
        }
        return this._syncRoot;
    }
}
```

This means you must cast to `ICollection` to use it.

Comment: Great, it is correct. I didn't know about explicit implementations, thanks.

Comment: Could it be advisable to have an explicit implementation of SyncRoot property even on my own classes? (I have custom implementations of collections) I think it could discourage the SyncRoot usage.

Comment: The use of SyncRoot is indeed discouraged in for that reason it is implemented explicitly. I find implementing members explicitly useful especially in two scenario's: 1. The use of the member has no use outside of the interface (see for instance this example: http://bit.ly/crLXAz) 2. The member has not been implemented and throws an exception (see for instance this example http://bit.ly/3RFzn4 where an `Add` method has no meaning on a `ReadOnlyDictionary`).

Comment: @Luca - Personally I would avoid relying on `SyncRoot` and instead use the new `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<T>` class. This can help reduce errors because you don't have to lock every action against the list.